# CKEditorError: track-changes-adapter-missing-getsuggestion: Adapter not set or is missing `getSuggestion()` method

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am trying to setup simple "load and save integration" with trackchanges in ckeditor5. I am getting the above error when I load the suggestion added in the editor.

As per documentation https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/collaboration/track-changes/track-changes-integration.html#loading-the-data

I dont want to add any adapter for load and save integration but I am not sure why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having suggestion in the texteditor content but json structure which I was passing inside the adapter does not have suggestions which was causing the issue.(data passing and retrieval issue)